# GitHub - License Not Recognised

Tags: github

I've got several GitHub repositories which are licensed using Apache 2.0, but some of them don't seem to recognise the license file.

An example of a repository that does recognise the license displays this:
[image]

[image]

An example of a repository that does not recognise the license displays this:
[image]

The license files themselves are binary identical, which I discovered by copying the license file from the *working* repository to the *not working* repository, and Git didn't detect a file change.

Are there any known issues to cause this, and if so, how do I fix?

Comment: What is your license file called?

Comment: @bk2204 LICENSE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case, try and rename it `LICENSE.txt` (or `LICENSE.md`) ans see if it makes any difference.

From [GitHub documentation "Detecting a license"](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/licensing-a-repository#detecting-a-license), GitHub uses [`licensee/licensee`](https://github.com/licensee/licensee) to detect a license file.

You could therefore:

- clone your second repository
- `gem install licensee`
- cd /path/to/cloned/repo
- `licensee detect .`

That way, you can check if locally the file is correctly detected.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not picked up, there may already be a file GH thinks is the license that is getting in the way of it recognizing the real license.  Look for a 'view license' link at the upper right of the code tab.  Clicking through will show you what file in the repo GH *thinks* is the license file, probably some unrelated file whose name happens to start with the word 'license'.  Delete/rename this unrelated file.  GH should now pick up the correct license file.

Answer (score 0):

1/ Rename yourlicense file with .md extension,
respect the case : LICENSE.md

2/ Click on Edit this file

3/ When editor is open click on the button
"Choose a license template"

4/ On the left menu, click on your license in the list

5/ Click on the right button "Review and submit"

6/ the system go-back to the edition page

7/ record the modification by clicking on "Commit changes"